# How to make an app run as a daemon on Ubuntu when installed?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, upstart, services, deb

I have a Java app - although the answer here should be the same regardless of whether it is Java, Ruby, Python, etc. - that I would like to distribute in such a way that when devops folk go to install it, it automagically runs as a daemon, with zero config on their side. My inspiration for this comes from the [Docker daemon](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/daemon), which is written in Go but that automagically configures itself as a daemon on Ubuntu machines. I want to do the same, but have no clue where to even begin.

I would *imagine* that either:

- I need to somehow package my app inside a `deb`; or
- Ship my app executable with necessary `init`/`systemd`/`upstart`/etc. scripts that somehow get installed
  locally without the end user having to run them. However, in this
  case, I’m not sure how to select which scripts to install as the user
  may have any one of several `init`-like tools setup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu (and Debian), creating a `deb` package would be the best way to go, as everything can be automated, so that no end-user intervention is needed. The only cases where package installation or upgrades are not automated are if the package has some configuration options that need input from the user (mainly during installation only) or if a configuration file was modified by the user and is also modified by a newer version of the package (during upgrading). In addition, after installing/upgrading a package, any startup scripts it installs are automatically started.

You can have multiple `init` scripts be installed, and have everything still work. In the case of `systemd` being installed and used on the user's computer, if there is both an `init` script and a `systemd` script for the same service, then the `init` script is ignored and the `systemd` script is used.

In terms of the packaging itself, Debian provides helper scripts that (among other things) automatically install any startup scripts you provide (I don't think `upstart` is supported by their helper scripts, since this is only used on Ubuntu) and start the service. For an example of the packaging, see [this](https://github.com/saiarcot895/dump1090/tree/0766ffc8b32b5a25dd6b8cb280e65b3915bae6f7/debian) `debian` folder for the `dump1090-mutability` package. (Disclaimer: this is my Github account) Note that the `dump1090-mutability.init` file contains the `init` script while the `dump1090-mutability.service` file contains the `systemd` script. Note that the names of these files should be `package-name.init` and `package-name.service`, where `package-name` is the name of the binary package being created. (See `man dh_systemd_enable` and `man dh_systemd_start` for the systemd case.)

On packaging, both of these files are placed in the appropriate directories on the user's system, and the service is then started. For the `rules` file, I recommend that you have something like the following, so that you benefit from the automation (see [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/pkg-systemd/Packaging?action=show&redirect=systemd%2FPackaging) for the `--with systemd` part):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@ --with systemd

override_dh_auto_build:
        # Specify how to build the Java files here, if there is no Makefile provided

override_dh_auto_install:
        # Specify how to install the Java files here, if there is no `install` target in the Makefile. Don't worry about anything in the `debian` directory unless you need to install some icons.
```

- If your app doesn't have a Makefile and is just a collection of Java source files, fill out `override_dh_auto_build` (where the source files are compiled and packaged into a JAR) and `override_dh_auto_install` (where the JAR is installed).
- If your app has a Makefile, but doesn't have an `install` target, remove the `override_dh_auto_build` target and fill out `override_dh_auto_install`.
- If your app has a Makefile and it has an `install` target (that can be used), remove both targets.
- If your app is just a JAR file, remove `override_dh_auto_build`, and fill out `override_dh_auto_install`.

Comment: Thanks @saiarcot895 (+1) - ideally I would not have to distribute sources and could just have the `deb` install the packaged JAR - is this possible? Either way, could you please update your answer to include a sample of what the directory structure would look like for the ZIP/TAR that I would ultimately distribute? I'd imagine this ZIP/TAR would contain the `deb` package, the install scripts, and the JAR, but am still fuzzy on how this would all look. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can choose to ship just the JAR file. See the last bullet point above. The `deb` file contains everything; you won't have any other files outside of the `deb` file to ship, so you don't need to put it in a zip/tar file.

Comment: Thanks again @saiarcot895 (+1) - last followup question, I promise! Is all of this Ubuntu-compatible, or does it just run on Debian? Thanks again!

Comment: Even better: it's Ubuntu and Debian compatible.

Comment: The building of the package itself will have to be on Ubuntu 15.04 or Debian Jessie (or newer), because of the `--with systemd` part, but, if needed, with a little more code, you can choose to compile on Ubuntu 14.04+ or Debian Wheezy and have the resulting package work on both `init` and `systemd` systems.